# RTSP-livestream with cardboard view

Tags: android

I just want to ask you, if it's possible to put the cardboardview on a RTSP-Player?

So, I have a livestream on the smartphone via RTSP (WIFI). But I want to play the video in der cardboard View (splitted and added effect).

So what do I need to create this Videoplayer? The source code of a RTSP-Player should be safe - there are thousands on github. Can anyone of you recommend a low-latency one?

Would be great if someone could help me,

Cheers

Comment: no I didn't, because I want to make sure, that my operation with the cardboardview is going to work. So if this won't work, i dont need a RTSP player.

Comment: But can you recommend anyone?